# Testing starting chars of two sentences against eachother

Tags: javascript

I'm working my way through Eloquent JavaScript and ran into this practice:

*Write a function called startsWith that takes two arguments, both strings. It returns true when the first argument starts with the characters in the second argument, and false otherwise.*

Here's the answer they gave:

```
function startsWith(string, pattern) {
return string.slice(0, pattern.length) == pattern;
}

show(startsWith("rotation", "rot"));
```

But I wanted a more thorough program that would take the start characters `chars` and test them in each sentence and spit out whether the starting characters were the same in each sentence. I'm new to JavaScript and Programming, so any help would be appreciated! Here's what I thought would work:

```
var sentenceOne = "Pretty kitty doesn't like you!";
var sentenceTwo = "Preachy cat loves you.";
function startsWith(chars) {
  return (sentenceOne.slice(0, chars.length) == chars) == (sentenceTwo.slice(0, chars.length) == chars);
}
show(startsWith("pre"));
```

Comment: (sentenceOne.slice(0, chars.length) == chars) && (sentenceTwo.slice(0, chars.length) == chars);

Comment: It may work, but a more clear way to do it is: `return sentenceOne.slice(0, chars.length) === chars && sentenceTwo.slice(0, chars.length) === chars;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given is pretty thorough. Given two sentences you could simply do:

```
var sentenceOne = "Pretty kitty doesn't like you!";
var sentenceTwo = "Preachy cat loves you.";

show(startsWith(sentenceOne, "Pre") === startsWith(sentenceTwo, "Pre"));
```

You don't need an entirely new function which simply checks whether two strings start with the same pattern. See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p3unn/1/

---

Another way to do it is, given two sentences and a pattern you could test whether the starting characters are the same:

```
function startWith(sentenceOne, sentenceTwo, pattern) {
    return !(sentenceOne.indexOf(pattern) || sentenceTwo.indexOf(pattern));
}
```

Now you simply do:

```
show(startWith(sentenceOne, sentenceTwo, "Pre"));
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p3unn/2/

Answer (score 0):

You've almost had it, but you also have to pass the `sentenceOne` and `sentenceTwo` through parameters (let's call them `firstSentence` and `secondSentence`) to your function so it can work with them. Otherwise, that information is out of the scope of the function!

```
var sentenceOne = "Pretty kitty doesn't like you!";
var sentenceTwo = "Preachy cat loves you.";
function startsWith(chars, firstSentence, sencondSentence) {
  return (sentenceOne.slice(0, chars.length) == chars) == (sentenceTwo.slice(0, chars.length) == chars);
}
show(startsWith("pre"), sentenceOne, sentenceTwo);
```